# Scala Polymorphic Function Type Mismatch

Tags: scala, functional-programming, polymorphism, tail-recursion

When trying to run a polymorphic function that abstracts over the type of the array, I get a type mismatch with the following error message:

> Type mismatch: expected: (Int) => Boolean, actual: Int

```
  val listIntegers = List(55, 50, 25, 23, 21, 16, 15)

  def abstractSearchKey[A](a: List[A], p: A => Boolean): Int = {
    def loop(n: Int): Int ={
      if (n > a.length) -1
      else if (p(a(n))) n 
      else loop(n+1)
    }
    loop(0)
  }

  abstractSearchKey[Int](listIntegers, 25)
```

I'm confused about this error message because this exercise is based on Chiusano's Functional Programming with Scala. In fact, on page 24, the authors state:

> ...the p function must accept a value of type A (since it's a function of type A => Boolean)

Any advice or feedback on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are expecting a function (a predicate of type `Int => Bool` )as the second argument of `abstractSearchKey`, and you are pasing `25` which is an `Int`.

Try passing a lambda function like `x => x > 20`, for example, to be able to cut the loop using this predicate:

```
abstractSearchKey[Int](listIntegers, x => x > 20)
```

Edit: SergGr from the comments just pointed out that you might want this function: `x => x == 25` instead, so it might be:

```
abstractSearchKey[Int](listIntegers, x => x == 25)
```

Comment: But looking at the example in the question it probably should be `x => x == 25`. Or the type of `p` should be changed to just `A` and the `if` inside `loop` should become something like  `if (p == a(n)) n`

Comment: Yes, if you want to return the index whose element is `25`, you should use `x => x == 25`. You didn't mention that in the question so I used a random function.

Comment: nicodp, I just want to mention that I'm not mberet so my comment is just a guess based on my interpretation of the question's code example: `listIntegers` contains `25` and this is also the argument that is being passed to `abstractSearchKey`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, I think he wants that function to be passed, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Worked like a charm :)